# Where are Chrome Settings Stored in Android 4.4.2

Tags: chrome-for-android

I am configuring a lot of devices and one thing we have to do is turn off Autofill in Chrome. Is there a way to drop a settings file in a folder that contains this setting or do we have to manually go in and turn it off through Chrome settings?

I'm sure this will require root access but is there a settings.xml file or something where this information is stored?

Answer (score 1):

I finally rooted a device to determine the exact location. There is a Preference file located in the following directory.

```
/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default
```

This Preference file stores the settings. Unfortunately, you can't write to it without Root access.